# Why do Joey and Chandler shut off the VCR?

Tags: plot-explanation, friends

In *Friends* S05E19, Joey's grandma comes to visit. He was supposed to be in a TV series, but the director cut his scene. Joey brings a newly recorded tape for his grandma. We see Chandler singing David Bowie's *Space Oddity*, and Joey and Chandler rush to shut off the VCR. What did they not want Joey's grandma to see?

Comment: ["Desperate not to shock his grandmother, he records himself on tape at his apartment in a crime scene where he holds his duck hostage. The clip is pretty crude, as he doesn't even change the sweater he's wearing. But the clip is good enough for Nonni - that is, until the video tape continues rolling, showing Chandler sing Space Oddity in front of the camera."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_One_Where_Ross_Can%27t_Flirt)

Comment: Why do they hide that particular scene and just closes after Chandler singing it

Comment: Just to avoid Grandma from realizing that the scene was recently shot?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The truth they didn't want to show was that the scene on TV was faked. If grandma sees singing Chandler right after Joey's appearance, she would have understood that it was not a real broadcasting (because Chandler was not an actor and couldn't be in on TV in the same series).

Comment: ok plausible but still if they had this thing they wouldn't have rushed.And fyi if the grandma couldn't figure out that so called Joey was acting in a recorded tape could she have figured out that

Comment: Why do you think they wouldn't have rushed? And it was not "so called Joey" it was Joey himself on the tape.

Comment: yea to hide the fact but why does both of them rushed Joey could have easily turned it off and grandma wouldn't have know but why Chandler did then

Comment: ..or they could have turn off the TV. There were several possibilities to conceal the fact of the fake, Joey and Chandler have chosen this.